# How to Configure Dart plugin in eclipse and Dartium in Fedora 18 x86_64

Tags: dart

Am getting errors when installing dart plugin in eclipse 4.2 the error is 
  An error of will appear as it happened to me  =>  /usr/lib64/eclipse/dart-sdk.zip (Permission denied)

and dartium for linux is giving me an error of

./chrome: error while loading shared libraries:  libbz2.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

and an another error

./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you post this as an answer? See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to

Comment: @tjameson thanks for that information and i have corrected as advised

Answer (score 1):

This is to help anyone who comes into these errors while configuring Dart and Dartium when using the fedora 18 os

- When installing the dart plugin in eclipse {I am using Eclipse from the fedora official repository which is Juno 4.2.1 &&    any  4.2 and above will work with this procedure }

  - add the following URL [ http://www.dartlang.org/eclipse/update ] to the list of available software sites in your Eclipse installation (Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites):
  - After  the downloading and installation procesess finish you will be asked to restart eclipse .
  - An error of will appear as it happened to me  =>  /usr/lib64/eclipse/dart-sdk.zip (Permission denied) 
    -Panic not but if you try to change permission on the  /usr/lib64/eclipse/ may be to chmod -R 777 eclipse will fail to start 
    if you do so change back to chmod -R 755 .it will start normally .
    -The solution i used was to comment this line -preventMasterEclipseLaunch
    on top of eclipse.ini.
    -Install the dart plugin and you are off to dart web apps creation.
    -If you also need the dartium working errors of :

    1. ./chrome: error while loading shared libraries:  libbz2.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
       it might complain of  ./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

  2 ./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  it might complain of  ./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Two solutions i have for this are :
 1.Locate the location of the two libraries in your system and do symlinks to either /usr/lib/ or to usr/lib64 
   as below :
you can use the locate command or find command 
  locate libbz2.so.1.0
if  found do ln -s  {/path/to/libbz2.so.1.0} {/path/to/dartium/libbz2.so.1.0}
  later do 
 locate libudev.so.0
if  found do ln -s  {/path/to/libudev.so.0} {/path/to/dartium/libudev.so.0}

1. if you have google chrome already in your system you can copy the 
   two libraries from the installation directory of your chrome 
   what i did was 
     cp -rfv /opt/google/chrome/libbz2.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/
     cp -rfv /opt/google/chrome/libudev.so.0 /usr/lib64/
   3.Start chromium with 
   cd  {/path/to/dartium/}
    them do chmod +x chrome
   start it by on your terminal  or konsole type ./chrome